# I need a django filter query that takes a string as argument and it gets matched the REGEXS stored in my model

Tags: django-models

I have a model

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    pattern = models.CharField('Regex Pattern',max_length=200)
```

i have created 100 entries in this model with different regex values,
now i want to query the model such that if the string I pass matches any of the regexes, then that object should be returned

i am trying to do the exact OPPOSITE of the following (where fields are normal strings and regex is being passed in the argument)

Book.objects.filter(title__iregex=r'^.{10,}$')

I tried Stackoverflow but all i could find is that there is a standard way for the opposite.
I tried multiple AI but all failed.

Answer (score 0):

Inject a string with [**`.alias(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#alias), then use an [**`F`** expression <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/expressions/#django.db.models.F):

```
from django.db.models import F, Value

MyModel.objects.alias(val=Value('my_string')).filter(
    val__iregex=F('pattern')
)
```

This "*trick*" can essentially be used to make an opposite lookup for any string.

Another option is to essentially do what Django does behind the curtains: translate the expression to lookup-objects:

```
from django.db.models import F, Value
from django.db.models.lookups import Regex

MyModel.objects.filter(Regex(Value('my_string'), F('pattern')))
```

To some extent, I always find it a bit bizarre that the documentation in Django does not tell much about lookups, and how these can be used to effectively query the database.

Comment: This is so so helpful, unfortunately my votes are not counted yet but i have upvoted your response.

It is very helpful and I will mention your contribution in my project! :D Thanks

Comment: [link] (https://github.com/TheAbhilash23/django_rest_authorization) 

Thanks @willeM_VanOnsem